# Return everything where not in X but in X

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a table Account:

[image: DatabaseTable]

I only want practiceid's that only have account type 'ledger' or 'debit'. If they have that + any of the others I don't want it.

Somehow this doesn't cut it:

```sql
SELECT PracticeId, accounttype 
FROM Account
WHERE AccountType IN('debit' , 'Ledger')
```

I'm only supposed to get practiceid 100 and 105 back.

How can I have a query that will only give me practices that have only either ledger or debit or both?

Comment: whats wrong in this query SELECT PracticeId, accounttype FROM Account WHERE AccountType IN('debit' , 'ledger')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like the following which will filter for `practiceId` that has both `debit` and `ledger` but then uses a WHERE clause to remove any `practiceIds` that have other `accountTypes`:

```
SELECT PracticeId, accounttype 
FROM Account 
WHERE AccountType IN('debit' , 'Ledger')
  and practiceid not in (select practiceid
                         from account
                         where AccountType not IN('debit' , 'Ledger'));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/793fe/2). This returns:

```
| PRACTICEID | ACCOUNTTYPE |
----------------------------
|        100 |      ledger |
|        100 |       debit |
|        105 |      ledger |
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick.And by the way, thank you for the tool

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
SELECT PracticeId
FROM   Account
GROUP BY PracticeId
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN AccountType IN( 'debit', 'Ledger' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first select all rows that have a different accouttype and then use not in:

```
SELECT PracticeId, accounttype FROM Account 
WHERE id NOT IN(
SELECT id FROM Account
WHERE accounttype NOT in('debit' , 'Ledger')
)
```